# Improving the speed of cross-referencing rows in the same DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to apply a complex function to a pandas DataFrame, and I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do it. A simplified version of my data looks like this:

```
UID,UID2,Time,EventType
1,1,18:00,A
1,1,18:05,B
1,2,19:00,A
1,2,19:03,B
2,6,20:00,A
3,4,14:00,A
```

What I want to do is for each combination of UID and UID2 check if there is both a row with EventType = A and EventType = B, and then calculate the time difference, and then add it back as a new column. So the new dataset would be:

```
UID,UID2,Time,EventType,TimeDiff
1,1,18:00,A,5
1,1,18:05,B,5
1,2,19:00,A,3
1,2,19:03,B,3
2,6,20:00,A,nan
3,4,14:00,A,nan
```

This is the current implementation, where I group the records by UID and UID2, then have only a small subset of rows to search to identify whether both EventTypes exist. I can't figure out a faster one, and profiling in PyCharm hasn't helped uncover where the bottleneck is.

```
for (uid, uid2), group in df.groupby(["uid", "uid2"]):
    # if there is a row for both A and B for a uid, uid2 combo
    if len(group[group["EventType"] == "A"]) > 0 and len(group[group["EventType"] == "D"]) > 0:
        time_a = group.loc[group["EventType"] == "A", "Time"].iloc[0]
        time_b = group.loc[group["EventType"] == "B", "Time"].iloc[0]

        timediff = time_b - time_a
        timediff_min = timediff.components.minutes

        df.loc[(df["uid"] == uid) & (df["uid2"] == uid2), "TimeDiff"] = timediff_min
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to make sure `Time` column is a `timedelta`

```
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)
df.Time = df.Time - pd.to_datetime(df.Time.dt.date)
```

After that I create a helper dataframe

```
df1 = df.set_index(['UID', 'UID2', 'EventType']).unstack().Time
df1
```

[image]

Finally, I take the diff and merge to `df`

```
df.merge((df1.B - df1.A).rename('TimeDiff').reset_index())
```

[image]

Comment: Magic, thanks! I'll need to tweak it to get that last TimeDiff value as a number of minutes rather than a timedelta, but that's a trivial problem compared to the original.